# Prove that if $a \ge b$ then $C(a,b,m)$ is true if and only if $\exists r\colon a = rm + b$ where $r$ is a natural.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have this problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

> Define the following predicate $C(a,b,m)$  for naturals $a,b$, and positive naturals $m$. If $a<m$, $C(a,b,m)$ is true if and only if $a=b$. If $b \ge m$, then $C(a,b,m)$ is false. Otherwise $C(a,b,m)$ is true is and only if $C(a-m,b,m)$ is true. Prove that if $a \ge b$ then $C(a,b,m)$ is true if and only if $\exists r\colon a = rm + b$ where $r$ is a natural.

What I originally did was translate this entire statement into a propositional statement, but from there I really do not know where to go.

Comment: Either you’ve miscopied the problem, or there’s an error in your source, because the result is stated is false. It would be correct if the first clause were that $C(a,b,m)$ is true if $a=b$.

Comment: Sorry about that that is what I meant. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Okay; then I’ll roll it back to @Hagen’s edit, which made that correction and prettied it up a bit.

Comment: Pick $m=3$, $a=10$, $b=7$. Then $C(a,b,m)$ is false by the second clause, but we have $a\ge b$ and $a=rm+b$ with $r=1$. - Check the problem statement again.

Comment: What do you mean by check the problem statement again @HagenvonEitzen